# Regular expression: find function calls

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to search a php file to find all calls to a functions I've defined in that file.  I've got an array that contains all of the functions I want to search for.  If the function's name is `Foo`, then I've got:

```
match = re.search(r'!(function)Foo\(', line)
```

where `line` is the current line of code I'm looking at.  I want this to match (doesn't need to return anything, just tell me there was a match) all calls to the function, and not match when the function is declared.  (I'm brand new to regex, but I'm already seeing how I now have two problems)

Comment: So you want it also to match for lines that call the function?

Comment: Yeah, the term "use" was probably poor language on my part.  Editing.

Comment: Why not use PHP's [`token_get_all`](http://www.php/.net/token_get_all), preparsed and ready for your use, a lot more reliable then searching with regexes.

Comment: @Wrikken Because I'm writing this in Python (trying to stretch my Python skills)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need some lookbehind:

```
re.search(r'(?<!function) Foo\(', line)
```

It'll not match if `function` is placed before `Foo`.

Comment: @SomeKittens Just to make it a raw string. BTW, it's the same thing you did